# Android - ActionBar not resizing with onConfigurationChanged ( AppCompat )

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

In my application manifest I've add **android:configChanges** to prevent activity reload/restart on rotate

```
<activity
  android:name=".MainActivity"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" >
```

it works, but supportActionBar ( I'm using AppCompat ) preserves his height with small font size.

ActionBar should be bigger in portrait and smaller in landscape, but it keeps the initial value:

- if I start in landscape, the actionbar stay thin in portrait
- if I start in portrait, the actionbar stay big in landscape

Removing **android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"** is the only solution I've found, but the app restart on rotate, and I need to preserve application content

**Starting in portrait**
[image]

**Starting in landscape**
[image]

**Starting in landscape and rotating screen to portrait (small action bar and small font height)**
[image]

Answer (score 4):

By setting `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"`

You declare that you will handle these config changes by yourself. In normal cases, you should not set that, and let Android recreate your Activity.

Edit:

If you want to keep the line `android:configChanges`, you have to override `onConfigChanged()` and change everything needed by yourself, e.g. the size of the ActionBar/ToolBar.

Comment: Yes, but i need to preserve my content.. What should i do?

Comment: What is the content your preserving? You should use onSaveInstanceState()

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html#SaveState check this link

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out you should save and restore the instance state instead of handling configuration changes yourself if possible. If you have good reason not to do that you can try to update the toolbar's height and text appearance after the configuration change.

The following code should work for the support library version of `Toolbar`. The attributes `actionBarSize`, `titleTextAppearance` and `subtitleTextAppearance` are provided by the support library.

The code assumes that you have a custom attribute `appToolbarStyle` declared in `attrs.xml`. If you don't need that you can adapt the code to use `R.style.Widget_AppCompat_Toolbar` directly instead.

```
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

...

private Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    updateToolbar();
}

private void updateToolbar() {
    if (toolbar == null)
        return;

    final Context context = toolbar.getContext();

    int[] attr = new int[] { R.attr.actionBarSize, R.attr.appToolbarStyle };
    int idxActionBarSize = 0;
    int idxAppToolbarStyle = 1;
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attr);
    int actionBarSize = a.getDimensionPixelSize(idxActionBarSize, 0);
    int appToolbarStyle = a.getResourceId(idxAppToolbarStyle, R.style.Widget_AppCompat_Toolbar);
    a.recycle();

    if (actionBarSize != 0) {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = toolbar.getLayoutParams();
        if (layoutParams != null) {
            layoutParams.height = actionBarSize;
        }

        toolbar.setMinimumHeight(actionBarSize);
    }

    attr = new int[] { R.attr.titleTextAppearance, R.attr.subtitleTextAppearance };
    int idxTitleTextAppearance = 0;
    int idxSubtitleTextAppearance = 1;
    a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(appToolbarStyle, attr);
    int titleTextAppearance = a.getResourceId(idxTitleTextAppearance, 0);
    int subtitleTextAppearance = a.getResourceId(idxSubtitleTextAppearance, 0);
    a.recycle();

    if (titleTextAppearance != 0) {
        toolbar.setTitleTextAppearance(context, titleTextAppearance);
    }

    if (subtitleTextAppearance != 0) {
        toolbar.setSubtitleTextAppearance(context, subtitleTextAppearance);
    }

    toolbar.requestLayout();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep `android:configChanges`, you can use this to force **56dp** toolbar height, align icons and fix small text issue:

Toolbar XML:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:minHeight="56dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/titleTextAppearance" />
```

Styles XML:

```
<style name="titleTextAppearance" parent="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: beware, the default for sw600dp should be `64dp`