# How to detect orientation changes but letting android handle them?

Tags: android, screen-orientation, android-lifecycle, oncreate, android-orientation

I have an issue very similar to this: [Android - ActionBar not resizing with onConfigurationChanged ( AppCompat )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32434609/android-actionbar-not-resizing-with-onconfigurationchanged-appcompat)

I need to let android handle orientation changes, because i want to get the activity recreated.

But also, i need to detect when a orientation change has been produced.

Are these two combined needs able to be achieved at once?